# Pandas - Return rows that only contain integers

Tags: pandas, dataframe

From a whole DataFrame, i picked a specific column.

Once I have this column (which is of type object) i want to return all the rows that have integers only.

Consider the following DataFrame.

```
Fruits     Vegetable 
    
Apple      Corn
123        Potatoe
```

```
subDf=df["Fruits"]
```

What can i use on subDf so that it returns all rows that contain only integers?

(In this case "123")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `str.contains` here:

```py
subDf = df[df["Fruits"].str.contains(r'^\d+$')]
```

`str.contains` uses the following regular expression, which means:

```regex
^    from the start of the Fruits value
\d+  match one or more digits (integer only)
$    end of the value
```

Comment: Wow this works, can i ask what r'^\d+$' does? Does this expression return any string that contains only number? What do the characters in r'^\d+$' mean?

Comment: Let me add an explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Should brush up on regular expressions